# Visual Studio 2012 and MVC4 package query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

If I create an MVC4 project in VS2012 it creates a packages folder where the references to MVC4 dlls point to.

Why does it create this as MVC4 is installed as part of VS2012?

These assemblies are located @ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies" and I would expect the path to point to this location.

For example when I add a reference to System.Web.Http.SelfHost the path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies" and it is not added to the packages folder.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with MVC 4 we have adopted an approach to referencing binary dependencies via NuGet packages. Using NuGet packages means that it is easier for you to discover and download new versions of the binaries that you depend on. Additionally using packages means binaries are referenced as "CopyLocal=true" (aka a bin reference), which means that deploying your application is easier and you don't have to depend on your target server having the right set of frameworks installed; they're all there in your app's bin folder.

Comment: I've got copy local = true on System.Web.Helpers which was added through NuGet, yet it still doesn't publish. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296538/system-web-helpers-not-being-published-by-visual-studio-2012